# Хочу создать папку пользователя, в которой будет находиться файл и в этой файле будет сохранён пример от этого пользователя и ответ от бота на пример

Tags: python, aiogram, бот

```
if not os.path.exists('users'): 
     os.mkdir('users')

@dp.message(Command(commands='start'))
async def start(message: types. Message):
   
    if not os.path.exists(f'users/{message.from_user.id}'):
            os.mkdir(f'users/{message.from_user.id}')
            with open(f'users/{message.from_user.id}/primery.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
                file.write('')
    else:
        None

    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, text= 'Спасибо, что используете нашего бота. Напишите пример для решения')
```